# Java Tree Data Structure Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Can someone point me to the **standard, tested, simple Tree implementation in Java**?

For example, all StackOverflow searches on Java Trees lead to this topic,
[Tree implementation in Java (root, parents and children)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330731/tree-implementation-in-java-root-parents-and-children)

but then you discover that the Accepted Answer in that topic doesn't work and gives an Overflow Exception (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40622616/1005607) -- very dangerous, maybe someone should delete or edit that answer or at least move it down.

There are some non-StackOverflow resources but once again I don't know how reliable they are,
http://programtalk.com/java/java-tree-implementation/

I find it hard to believe there's no reusable robust implementation we can go to quickly. The node should track its Parent and Children. There should be no errors.

Comment: I used Data Structures and-Algorithm Analysis in Java by Mark Allen Weiss ,in tree section there is a nice implementation of tree

Answer (score 2):

The problem of the question that you showed (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40622616/1005607) is that the methods `addChild` and `setParent` calls each other in an infinite loop.

```
public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
    parent.addChild(this);  // Call addChild
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
    child.setParent(this);   // Call setParent
    this.children.add(child);
}
```

You need to modify it as follow:

```
// Make this method private
private void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
    // Remove this line to prevent the loop
    // parent.addChild(this);
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
    child.setParent(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}
```